# Convert Path String to Object Path in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-string

```
struct Student{
  var rollNum : Int
  var name : String
  var contact : Contact
}
struct Contact{
  var phoneNum : String
  var mailId : String
}

let contact = Contact(phoneNum : "1234567890", mailId : "abcd@xyz.com") 
let student = Student(rollNum : 1, name : "John", contact : contact)
```

Here, the path for mail Id is given as a String "Student/contact/mailId". How to convert this to Object Path as Student.contact.mailId?

Assume the label wants to display the mail ID, I would give the path string as "Student/contact/mailId" and the label should display the mail id as abcd@xyz.com

Comment: What exactly is an "Object Path"? Do you mean a KeyPath or something else?

Comment: ` 
let contact = Contact(phoneNum : "1234567890", mailId : "abcd@xyz.com")
let student = Student(rollNum : 1, name : "John", contact : contact)
`
Consider a label and it's text is given by this object path (i.e) Assume the label wants to display the mail ID, I would give the path string as "Student/contact/mailId" and the label should display the mail id as abcd@xyz.com  
@joakim-danielson

Comment: You should add that info to the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
Thanks!! Added further info...Kindly let me know if u get the solution

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why would you access the mailId via ' path ' instead of accessing via object chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Student {
    var rollNum: String
    var name: String
    var contact: Contact
}
struct Contact {
    var phoneNum: String
    var mailId: MailId
}
struct MailId {
    var official : String
    var personal : String
}
let pathString = "Student/contact/mailId/personal"
let pathComponents = pathString.components(separatedBy: "/")
var index : Int = 1

let contact = Contact(phoneNum: "9988998899", mailId: MailId(official: "official@gmail.com", personal: "personal@gmail.com"))
let student = Student(rollNum: "123", name: "John", contact: contact)



Reflection(from: student , pathComponents: pathComponents)
func Reflection(from object : Any, pathComponents : [String]) {
    let properties = Mirror(reflecting: object)
    for property in properties.children{
        if index < pathComponents.count{
            if property.label == pathComponents[index] {
                index += 1
                print(property.value , "got here with label :" , property.label)
                Reflection(from: property.value, pathComponents: pathComponents)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we can get the value as
`personal@gmail.com`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions to your problem. I think my solution could give an idea of how can you solve this problem.

```
struct Student {
    var rollNum: Int
    var name: String
    var contact: Contact
}

struct Contact {
    var phoneNum: String
    var mailId: String
}

func studentInformation(student: Student, paths: [String]) {
    print("Student name: \(student.name), RollNumber: \(student.rollNum)")
    if paths[0] == "\(Contact.self)" {
        contactInformation(contact: student.contact, path: paths[1])
    }
}

func contactInformation(contact: Contact, path: String) {
    print("Contact phonenumber: \(contact.phoneNum), mailId: \(contact.mailId)")
    let contactVariableNameWithValue = Mirror(reflecting: contact).children
    for variableName in contactVariableNameWithValue {
        if variableName.label == path {
            print(variableName.value)
            break
        }
    }
}

let contact = Contact(phoneNum: "1234567890", mailId: "abcd@xyz.com")
let student = Student(rollNum: 1, name: "John", contact: contact)
var pathString = "Student/Contact/mailId"
public let pathComponents = pathString.components(separatedBy: "/")
studentInformation(student: student, paths: Array(pathComponents.suffix(from: 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks @md-abul-kashem , It greatly helped me to solve my problem